# Как передать параметр из одного ТабКонтролер в другой ТабКонтролер через Навигатор Контролер?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Нужно передать параметр через промежуточный НавКонтролер.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"A1"]) {

        int *param = 999;
        UINavigationController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        tvc3 *destController =
        [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        destController.param = param;
```

Выдает ошибки - не знает `navigationController и viewControllers`. Как еще можно?

**Обновление**

Заменил строку

```
tvc3 *destController =
[[destViewController.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
destController.param = param;
```

Больше не ругается. Но параметр не меняется в итоговом контроллере остается пустым.